# Grand Total is incorrectly displayed with Calculated Field in pivot table

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, pivot-table, array-formulas

I tried using a calculated field for a pivot table in Google Sheets. For example, there are two pivot table columns, `Column1` and `Column2`, containing numbers.

In the calculated field, I write for example `=Column1+Column2`. In my case, this is the exact formula:

`=ROUNDDOWN((Cheating*25)-('Not Cheating'*100), -3)`

The result is correctly displayed. However, when it comes down to the grand totals, it will consider those values as standard values and calculate them the same way instead of displaying the grand totals for the above cells.

The current solution I use is a column outside of the pivot table and just calculate with ARRAYFORMULA. This way, I can tell the formula that it will only calculate for the columns that have values in a third column, so the grand totals are not calculated the same way.

[image]

Is there a way I can either use calculated field with proper grand totals (this is what I would prefer), or the ARRAYFORMULA with grand totals at the bottom of the formula calculation?

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H9uzZsaMc8eT00i3BvLlTM_1xPSIQg4dF7nGgUSC-eE/edit#gid=823968835) is a spreadsheet with two examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pivot Table values have no impact on the custom formula in the Pivot Table report. It instead uses values from the original data. Thus, the source data, not the data from the pivot table, should be the basis for the calculation.

Even if the source's grand total is used, it is still handled as a regular value, and it had better be disabled.

You can try this approach until you share a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

```
ArrayFormula(IF(A3:A="Grand Total",,[The rest of the formula]))
```

### Update

You are using =[**`ROUNDDOWN`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093442?hl=en) Like this

```
=ROUNDDOWN((A3*25)-(B3*100), -3)
```

When setting the places to -3 it will round down the whole part "the numbers on the left of the point." 3 places to the left will be 000 see this example.

```
The input is 826.646

Output   Formula
826     =ROUNDDOWN(826.646, 0)  
826     =ROUNDDOWN(826.646) 
826.6   =ROUNDDOWN(826.646, 1)  
826.64  =ROUNDDOWN(826.646, 2)  
820     =ROUNDDOWN(826.646, -1) 
800     =ROUNDDOWN(826.646, -2)
```

[image]

### The sloution

Try

```
=ROUNDDOWN((Cheating*25)-('Not Cheating'*100), 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for responding! Referencing the source data, do you mean in the calculated field formula (so instead of naming the pivot table columns, I would name the columns of the source data instead)? If so, how would I do it? I tried Sheetname!X2:X as an example, but that did not seem to work. As for the suggested snippet, I assume this is for the ARRAYFORMULA outside of the pivot table? I am not sure how it is different from the current formula there, as it seems to achieve the same goal. Regarding minimal example, I thought snippet and screenshot were enough - should I add spreadsheet link?

Comment: If you prefer `ARRAYFORMULA` outside of the pivot table no need to add minimal example for me speaking. Referencing the source data meant When the pivot table calculated field was utilized, the pivot table's field formula looked at the source data rather than considering the pivot table as a source.

Comment: Hmm... I tried to create a new table of some simple data for your minimal example. Then everything is suddenly perfect... Maybe there is something wrong with the other data? Do you mind taking a look? I added a spreadsheet example to the post above with two parts: my data where pivot table is messed up and example data where pivot table is perfect @Osm

Comment: Hi @hofebido The answer is updated see if this solved.

Comment: Oh @Osm thank you, now it shows correct sum, but the reason I chose -3 was to round down to the nearest thousand, so without that the column is useless for me lol

Comment: I don't think it answers the question tho, now I got a new problem (no longer rounded down to nearest thousand)

Comment: If necessary, you may ask another follow-up question. and accept this. only if it tide to this question original problem, what did you find.

Comment: alrighty, will just accept and ask another question then, thanks :)