# How to use ROUNDDOWN() in pivot table's calculated field and return correct grand totals?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, calculated-field

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73843246/grand-total-is-incorrectly-displayed-with-calculated-field-in-pivot-table/73843472?noredirect=1#comment130415900_73843472), I got to know that using ROUNDDOWN() in a pivot table's calculated field is what causes the grand total to display an incorrect value. So I want to ask, how to use ROUNDDOWN() in a pivot table's calculated field and still return correct grand totals? Specifically, how to use the one that rounds down to the nearest thousand (, -3)? How it is now (showing 0 when it is not near a thousand) is perfect, the only issue is how to show the grand total correctly with those zeroes instead of irrelevant non-thousand values

With ROUNDDOWN() (`=ROUNDDOWN((Cheating*25)-('Not Cheating'*100), -3)`):

[image]

Without ROUNDDOWN() (`=(Cheating*25)-('Not Cheating'*100)`):

[image]

I already have this formula outside of the pivot table as a temporary solution:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(J2:J <> "", ROUNDDOWN((K2:K*25)-(L2:L*100), -3), ""))`

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H9uzZsaMc8eT00i3BvLlTM_1xPSIQg4dF7nGgUSC-eE/edit#gid=823968835) is the spreadsheet with the source data.

Comment: Is this a correct understanding of your question? You would like the grand total of `Calculated Field` to be the sum of the rounded values; whereas currently it calculates the sum of the unrounded values, and then rounds that sum.

Comment: Exactly like that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short Answer: Not Possible

> How to use ROUNDDOWN() in pivot table's calculated field and return correct grand totals?

I don't think this is possible because what the pivot table is doing in the grand total row, is applying the same calculated formula to the individual grand totals in columns K and L.  It does not actually calculate the total of your calculated field column.

### Workaround

It's possible to get the pivot table to show the values you want, by adding a helper column to the spreadsheet:

1. Insert a column `I` after column `H` of your spreadsheet.  In `I1` put the following formula:

`I1`:

```
={"Weight";ARRAYFORMULA(ROUNDDOWN(COUNTIFS(E$2:E,E2:E,G$2:G,1)*25-COUNTIFS(E$2:E,E2:E,H$2:H,1)*100,-3)/COUNTIFS(E$2:E,E2:E,G$2:G+H$2:H>0,TRUE))}
```

2. Then, add that column as a value in your pivot table, using `SUM` as the summary statistic.

### Formula explanation

This part of the formula

```
ROUNDDOWN(COUNTIFS(E$2:E,E2:E,G$2:G,1)*25-COUNTIFS(E$2:E,E2:E,H$2:H,1)*100,-3)
```

calculates the rounded aggregate sum for each identifier, and places it in *every* row where that identifier is found.

Then `/COUNTIFS(E$2:E,E2:E,G$2:G+H$2:H>0,TRUE)` divides (averages) that value among all of the rows for that identifier, which allows the `SUM` in the pivot table to aggregate them properly.

The main idea is that we are calculating the `ROUNDDOWN` function outside the pivot table, so that the pivot table only views the already-rounded values.

I'm not sure this will give you correct totals for individual month-years, but you should be able to adapt it to do so with an additional condition on the `COUNTIFS`.

Comment: This is some real pro-level stuff, really grateful for your in-depth explanation here Aaron, super helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In a normal use case this rounddown only values with max length in the provided range.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(A2:A)<=ROW(A2:A),
                 IF(LEN((A2:A*25)-(B2:B*100))=MAX(LEN((A2:A*25)-(B2:B*100))),ROUNDDOWN((A2:A*25)-(B2:B*100),-3),(A2:A*25)-(B2:B*100))))
```

[image]

In the pivot table, **calculated field** put

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN((Cheating*25)-('Not Cheating'*100))>4,ROUNDDOWN((Cheating*25)-('Not Cheating'*100),-3),(Cheating*25)-('Not Cheating'*100)))
```

[image]

**Note:**
Keep in mind `...>4...` in the formula decides when to rounddoun if the `LEN` length of the value is greater than `>4` then rounddoun.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this solves it for me - it's perfect that it says 0 if it is lower than any nearest 1 thousand, because in my use case, 0 means they are not eligible for consideration. Instead of returning 25, 50, 75, minus values and the other non-thousand values, is it possible to return 0 and still return correct grand totals (counting zeroes instead of those other irrelevant non-thousand values)? I'll update my post to clarify